# Time entry in hh:mm form

Tags: java

I'm creating an application in Java, and I have a textfield where I want to enter start time and another where I will enter endtime. And after these entries, I would like to see the time difference in the form hh:mm.

Example:

> Start time: 12:00
>   End time:  14:30
>
> Result:  2:30

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Get the time in milliseconds from your date-fields. Substract the 'from'-date from the 'to'-date. E.g.

```
toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()
```

Then you have the time-difference in milliseconds, simple matter of calculating into seconds, hours, days etc.

```
milliseconds / 1000
```

for seconds etc.

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful to you learn about [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse and format Date objects.

To parse date in you text field use

```
    // use "hh:mm" if you work in 12-hour format or
    // use "HH:mm" if you work in 24-hour format
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try
    {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(startTextField.getText());
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        //TODO don't forget process exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The two answers given so far are both correct, but I think they would best be utilized together.

Like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(startTextField.getText());
    Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(endTextField.getText());

    long differenceMillis = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    resultTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(differenceMillis)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    resultTextField.setText("ERROR");
}
```

See [this Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all the encoding schemes. Note that this method will drop a difference in in days, and only report hours.